# Regex replace in sql grouping

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace in an sql grouping condition the fields with a casted version of the fields:

for example:

```
input: sum(count(andrei) + count(2) + sum(count3)

ouptput: sum(count(cast(andrei as int)) + count(cast(2 as int)) + sum(cast(count3 as int))
```

My idea is to find literals that contain no "(" or ")" with the following pattern:

```
  Match m = Regex.Match(input, "\\([^\\(\\)]+\\)");
```

and then replace them with the casted version.

I don't know how to perform the replace.

Comment: You need a Regex.Replace(). I hope this article will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

Comment: I strongly recommend you use a literal string when defining your expressions. RegEx has enough slashes already.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following pattern and replacement string.

Pattern: `(?<=\()([^()]+)(?=\))`

- `(?<=\()`: look-behind that matches (but doesn't consume) the opening parenthesis
- `([^()]+)`: numbered capture group with a negative character class to match anything except the opening and closing parentheses. There's no need to escape them when they appear inside the character class.
- `(?=\))`: look-ahead that detects the closing parenthesis

Replacement string: `cast($1 as int)` where `$1` refers to the first numbered capture group

```
string input = "sum(count(andrei)) + count(2) + sum(count3)";
string pattern = @"(?<=\()([^()]+)(?=\))";
string replacement = "cast($1 as int)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```